# Exclude mlocate.db from the Locate searches

Tags: linux, unix

Can the search be excluded in /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db? I just want you to look at the one I generated locally. With -d or modifying LOCATE_PATH, only the one created in local is added, but continue searching in /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/locate), the databases specified with the `-d` option should replace the default database.

If the `--statistics` option reports that the default database is used with your search, then check if there is an alias or something else in effect that adds `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` explicitely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have verified that with -d the one that is created in local is added to the one that has /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db as default. --statistics indicates both, but I want you to just look for the local one.

Comment: To rule out that only `LOCATE_PATH`and the `-d` option path you have specified contribute to the actual database paths, run the command `LOCATE_PATH="/custom/locate.db" locate -d /custom/locate.db --statistics`. It should print statistics for `/custom/locate.db` only.